# How to skip reading the timestamp in zabbix?

Tags: logging, monitoring, zabbix

I have created a zabbix alert to return log messages whenever there is any ERROR or WARNING in the file :

Item :

```
Type : Zabbix agent (active)

key : log[/usr/local/panorama/acs/standalone/log/server.log,WARN\s*\[|ERROR\s*\[,,,,\0]

Type of information : Log

Log Time Format : yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss,SSS
```

And an alert :

```
Name : Error/Warning log at {HOST.NAME} : {ITEM.VALUE}

Expression : {MyTemplate:log[/usr/local/abc/abc.log,WARN\s*\[|ERROR\s*\[*,,,,\0].strlen()}>0

Multiple Problem Generation : Checked
```

Example log message :

```
2015-05-02 19:20:55,919 ERROR [com.xyz.MyClass] some log message here
```

With this configuration, the alert that is being returned is :

```
Error/Warning log at CL MyHost : ERROR [
```

Could you please help me here? I want the other portion of the log message, i.e. the alert should be like this :

```
Error/Warning log at CL MyHost : [com.xyz.MyClass] some log message here
```

**Here I want to get the log message except the time stamp portion of it.**

Also, what is the convention to parse the millisecond portion of the time stamp? I am using "S". Not sure if that is ok.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is "the other portion of the log message"?

Comment: @asaveljevs I have updated the question. I want to the entire log message except the time stamp portion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the most important goal is to have "[com.xyz.MyClass] some log message here" as item value, then the following key seems to work:

```
log[/tmp/logfile.txt,WARN\s*|ERROR\s*(\[.*),,,,\1]
```

Unfortunately, by only capturing the specified part of the log message we lose the ability to parse the timestamp, because the timestamp is parsed on the server side, but the \1 is captured on the agent side.

Regarding parsing of milliseconds, it is not supported (see [log monitoring documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items)).

Comment: In the dashboard for "Last 20 issues" only part of the message is being displayed (First few words). Is there any way to configure maximum number of characters that should be displayed there?

Comment: You might wish to see patches in [ZBXNEXT-2448](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2448).

Comment: This is helpful. But, that's an unofficial patch and not yet bundled with the product? :-(

Comment: Yes, the patch attached in ZBXNEXT-2448 is unofficial and the issue remains to be solved in the main product.

Answer (score 0):

The following key for the item solves the problem :

```
log[/usr/local/abc/abc.log,"WARN\s*\[(.*)|ERROR\s*\[(.*)",,,,\1]
```

The alert now returns :

```
Error/Warning log at CL MyHost : com.xyz.MyClass] some log message here
```